# Replace with ChrW() in Mac - Working fine with Windows

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I have a sheet that is working perfectly on windows but giving a `1004 Application-defined or object defined error` on MAC.

This is the code that's erroring:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(12).Replace What:=" " & ChrW(8595), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I've checked and MAC seems to be OK with chrw(), although I could be wrong.

Comment: Just been reading this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chr-function and I now realise you can't use CHRW() but, I can get away with using CHR()

Answer (score 0):

Just been reading this msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/… and I now realize you can't use CHRW() but, I can get away with using CHR()

Comment: yup, "The `ChrW` function returns a String containing the Unicode character except on platforms where Unicode is not supported, in which case, the behavior is identical to the `Chr` function."

Comment: Mmm not off the top of my head. You’ll want to open a new question with a bit more context into your problem and recreating it